# HTML5 Correct Usage: Is this code correct?

Tags: html

I'm on a project involving converting HTML code to HTML5, and I'd like some feedback as to whether I'm coding correctly or not.

Here's my stripped-down code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jsp/fileFolderPath/css/global.css">

<!--[if IE 7]> <body class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <body class="ie8"> <![endif]-->

<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/tip.js"></script>
<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/jquery.calendar.js"></script>

<script src="/jsp/fileFolderPath/js/modernizer-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#whatsthis').mouseover(function(){
        tooltip.show('Tooltip text goes here');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        tooltip.hide();
    });

    $('#printthis').mouseover(function(){
        tooltip.show('&lt;strong&gt;Print&lt;/strong&gt;');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        tooltip.hide();
    }).click(function(){
        printCalendar();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- container start --> 
    <div id="container">

        <!-- header start --> 
        <header>
            <figure>
                <img src="headerImg.png" width="600" height="100" alt="header image">
            </figure>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <nav>
                <!-- header code goes here - this is actually an include file -->
            </nav>
        </header>       
        <!-- header end -->

        <nav>
            <!-- primary navigation start -->
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            test
            <!-- primary navigation end -->
        </nav>

        <!-- Application Name start -->
        <div id="applicationName">mySchedule <a href="#" id="whatsthis"><img src="images/what-this.png" width="21" height="21" alt=""></a>
            <!-- breadcrumbs start --> 
            <nav>
                <div id="breadcrumbs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#MyConnections">Home</a></li>
                        <li>&rarr;</li>
                        <li><a href="#Exhibitors">mySchedule</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- breadcrumbs end --> 
        </div>
        <!-- Application Name end -->

        <!-- Features Toolbar start -->
        <div id="features" class="right">
            <div class="featuresAddOn"> <a href="#" id="printthis">Print mySchedule</a></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Features Toolbar end -->

        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div> 

        <!-- Left Side Bar start -->
        <div class="left">
            <nav>
                <!-- Application Navigation start -->
                <div id="appMenuContainer">
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 class="firstitem"><a href="/jsp/Myclients/Myclients.jsp?action=ClientMyMatchTab">Client Matching</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 id="MyClient" class="menuitem header"><span><a href="/jsp/Myclients/Myclients.jsp">MyClients</a></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 id="MySched" class="menuitem header"> <span><a style ="cursor:default">MySchedule</a></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appMenu">
                        <h4 id="MyHel" class="menuitem lastitem"> <span><a href="/jsp/Myclients/help.jsp">Help</a></span></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Application Navigation end -->
            <nav>

            <!-- Alert Box start -->
            <aside>
                <div id="AlertBox" class="margin-bottom margin-top">
                    <div class="title">Alert</div>
                    <div class="contentAlert lastItem"> You have <span class="count New_Time">0</span> New Time Proposed Notifications. </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <!-- Alert Box ends -->
        </div>
        <!-- Left Side Bar end -->

        <section>
            <!-- Content -->
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </section>

        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
    <!-- container end --> 

    <footer>
        © MyCompany, Inc. 2011
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

- Among the requirements of the project
  are that the website use HTML5, and
  support IE7, IE8, and IE9. This is
  why I'm using conditionals for the
  stylesheets. **With the requirements specified, is this the correct approach?**

  The html is on a jsp page, which
  contains a lot of dynamic code. I did
  not include that in the example.

  I have 3 navigational areas - one in
  the header, the dashboard (underneath
  the top header), and the side
  navigation. **Do these each need ids?**

  The side navigation is the same as
  the breadcrumbs - **so should the
  breadcrumbs be encased within nav
  tags?**

  This is one page of several. The
  content on all of the pages appears
  within the div id="calendar" tag.
  This is dynamically replaced
  depending on the client. This page looks like a calendar/schedule, for which clients can set appointments. Other pages look like either table lists/shopping carts, or forms. Apart from updating
  the tags to HTML5, pretty much all
  content is built using divs, so I
  intend to leave them as such. I think
  they all should be encased withing
  section tags though. **With this description, is it appropriate to use the section tag here?**

  I encased the alert box underneath
  the left side navigation in aside
  tags. The alert box content is
  related to the calendar content - it alerts a client if an appointment has been set on the calendar - but
  wouldn't make sense if it stood on
  it's own. **Is this correct?**

BTW, I'm a web development contractor brought in on this project. So I'm basically updating existing code.

I've gone through other the other posts, other online references and a couple books. I think I'm on the right track. I just would like some confirmation before moving forward.

Thanks.

Stephen

UPDATE: OK. I've made updates to my code above based on all of the recommendations, and I ran it through a validator (successfully).

I'm still a little unsure about three things:

1. If I understand correctly HTML5Shiv is a workaround that enables HTML5 elements in older versions of IE. Modernizr does something similar and handles HTML5 elements and CSS3. I'm not sure if this helps with the alternate stylesheets I have for IE7 and IE8. These are there for display/design issues, so I believe I need to continue to refer to them until the code that uses those classes is updated. They have nothing to do with CSS3 specs.
2. Saeed mentioned using the figure tag. Had to look that one up. The first image I'm using is the header logo, which is on all pages. So, that sounds like that tag would work for the header logo. Alternately, I wouldn't use it for, say, the help link (what-this.png), which is just a question mark icon. **Correct?**
3. Regarding the header and footer, the reason I put the divs inside the tags was because there are styles attached to them. Since I removed them, I'll now add the styles to the header and footer tags. **Is that the correct way to do this? If not, where do the styles go?**

Thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of recommendations:

1. Don't use `<div id='header' />` inside `<header>`, because it ruins the purpose of being **semantic**
2. It's better to use a library to query the capabilities of the current browser (I strongly recommend [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com)).
3. Use HTML5Shiv (Google it) to make IE8- understand about HTML5 elements (it's a hack)
4. Put your `<img>` tags inside a `<figure>` tag.
5. User `<nav>` wherever you have a list of links. It's the navigation element's purpose.
6. Use Level 2 of DOM events (use something like jQuery, or `addEventListener` instead of `onmouseout` attribute, for example)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)  code

Answer (score 0):

- is useless, you have the header
- you need a html5shiv or something alike to style it in old IE's  or modernizer
- separate stayle and markup (put the last align in CSS)

http://validator.w3.org/check, you can chose HTML5 there to validate

also check out HTML5 boilerplate

Comment: `<img>` tags SHOULD NOT  be closed in HTML, only XHTML

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<head>
...

<!--[if IE 7]> <body class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <body class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <body class="ie9"> <![endif]-->

...
</head>
<body>
...
```

looks bogus. While it is ignored by non-IE browsers, for the IE versions given there you end up having the start tag of a body element inside the head element, which is certainly invalid.
I think something like this could work better:

```
<head>
...
</head>
<!--[if true]>
<![if IE 7]> <body class="ie7"> <![endif]>
<![if IE 8]> <body class="ie8"> <![endif]>
<![if IE 9]> <body class="ie9"> <![endif]>
<![if (!IE)|(lt IE 7)|(gt IE 9)]> <body> <![endif]>
<![endif]-->
<![if false]> <body> <![endif]>
```

(But I'm not sure if that `<!...>` non-comment in the last line is in fact valid HTML.)

Comment: The way that the classes are [best used](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) as seen in the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is this:
`<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]--> `